# Java : URLConnection setRequestProperty range issue relying on multithreaded process?

Tags: java, multithreading, urlconnection

I'm stuck trying to read by range a remote file.

According following trace sounds setRequestProperty is not performing its job (InputStream Length is nok to me except one .. the first one ???) ?

```
Task Runnable ID = 0 --> Requested Range Property = {Range=[bytes=0-93969]}

Task Runnable ID = 1 --> Resquested Range Property = {Range=[bytes=93970-187939]}

Task Runnable ID = 2 --> Requested Range Property = {Range=[bytes=187940-281909]}

Task Runnable ID = 3 --> Resquested Range Property = {Range=[bytes=281910-375883]}

Task Runnable ID = 0 --> InputStream Lenght = 93970 / StartByte = 0 / CurrentByte = 0 / EndByte = 93969

Task Runnable ID = 1 --> InputStream Length = 375883 / StartByte = 93970 / CurrentByte = 93970 / EndByte = 187939

Task Runnable ID = 3 --> InputStream Length = 375883 / StartByte = 281910 / CurrentByte = 281910 / EndByte = 375883

Task Runnable ID = 2 --> InputStream Length = 375883 / StartByte = 187940 / CurrentByte = 187940 / EndByte = 281909
```

My code is :

```
public class TaskRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static final int    BUFFER_SIZE     = 4092;

    private long                startByte;
    private long                currentByte;
    private long                endByte;


    private Task                task;
    private static int          idCounter       = 0;
    private int                 id;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private TaskRunnable() {
    }

    public TaskRunnable(Task task, long startByte, long endByte) {
        this.startByte = startByte;
        this.endByte = endByte;
        this.task = task;
        this.currentByte = startByte;
        this.id = idCounter++;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Download Runnable");

        Authenticator authenticator = task.getManager().getAuthenticator();
        if (authenticator != null) {
            Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
        }

        File targetFile;
        synchronized (this) {
            targetFile = new File(task.getTargetFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }

        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        URLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL _url = new URL(task.getSourceFileUrl().toString());
            Proxy proxy = task.getManager().getProxy();
            if (proxy != null) {
                urlConnection = _url.openConnection(proxy);
            } else {
                urlConnection = _url.openConnection();
            }
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + currentByte + "-" + endByte);
            System.out.println("Task Runnable ID = " + id + " --> Requested Range Property = " + urlConnection.getRequestProperties().toString());

            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            int len = 0;
            while (bufferedInputStream.read() != -1) {
                len++;
            }
            System.out.println("Task Runnable ID = " + id + " --> InputStream Length = " + len + " / StartByte = " + startByte + " / CurrentByte = " + currentByte + " / EndByte = " + endByte);

            bufferedInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Obviously it's my fault but not able to figure out what's wrong. Help more than welcome. Thks !

Note : all is running fine if using same code but single thread based.

Comment: What exactly is the point all this? Why are you measuring the length of a range when you already know the range? And what exactly is the purpose of multithreading it?

Comment: Obviously I'm doing more than getting length within real life. I'm using InpuStream to get my remote file bytes. InputStream parts are written to a local file using RandomAccessFile. Current issue is not able to get correct (well sized) InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a concurrent modification of the internal URLConnection state. Have you tried to invoke `URLConnection.setUseCaches(false)` ?

**Update**

Another global cache that affects a possible reusing of `URLConnection` objects is [ResponseCache](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ResponseCache.html). You should disable it at initialization by executing

```
ResponseCache.setDefault(null);
```

Comment: Thks for tips.
I've just tried but unfortunately such is not helping. behavior still same :-(

I agree "I suspect a concurrent modification" but I'm not able to point it at that time ...

Comment: Neither doing `URLConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false)` at initialization?

Comment: Tested but sorry such is not solving my current issue.

Comment: Hello. Thks for your time. But still not ok.

Despite :

ResponseCache.setDefault(null);

urlConnection.setDefaultUseCaches(false);

urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + currentByte + "-" + endByte);

Comment: Sorry to be persistent, but are you sure that you invoke `ResponseCache.setDefault(null)` **before** starting the threads?

Comment: I guess so.

ResponseCache.setDefault(null);

for (DonwloadTaskRunnable runnable : runnableList) {

  manager.getThreadPool().submit(runnable);

}

Comment: I'm working back on such. Still not have the clue but I've noticed all is working fine if (endByte - currentByte) is quite small (roughly less than 1Mb)  ... as far as such is increasing I'm facing issue. Any idea ?

Comment: I've found such comment : "When multiple ranges are requested, a server MAY coalesce any of the ranges that overlap, or that are separated by a gap that is smaller than the overhead of sending multiple parts, regardless of the order in which the corresponding byte-range-spec appeared in the received Range header field" Can it be the clue ? Is there a way to prevent coalesce process ? On my side no overlap but gap is 0 (joined parts download)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418230/http-range-request-property