# Http Range request property?

Tags: java, multithreading, http, download

I'm stucked writing some java code pieces trying to download by range a target file from a remote host. I'm expecting to download remote file by some chunks relying on some multithreaded process.

According following debug trace all is running well :

```
Task 2 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=59124782-88687172]}
Task 3 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=88687173-118249563]}
Task 0 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=0-29562390]}
Task 1 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=29562391-59124781]}
Task 2 --> RETURN_CODE = 206 ==> OK :-) !
Task 2 --> Start Byte = 59124782 / End Byte = 88687172 --> Total bytes = 29562391
Task 0 --> RETURN_CODE = 206 ==> OK :-) !
Task 0 --> Start Byte = 0 / End Byte = 29562390 --> Total bytes = 29562391
Task 3 --> RETURN_CODE = 206 ==> OK :-) !
Task 3 --> Start Byte = 88687173 / End Byte = 118249563 --> Total bytes = 29562391
Task 1 --> RETURN_CODE = 206 ==> OK :-) !
Task 1 --> Start Byte = 29562391 / End Byte = 59124781 --> Total bytes = 29562391
```

According following debug trace all is NOT running well :

```
Task 0 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=0-15308169]}
Task 3 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=45924510-61232679]}
Task 1 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=15308170-30616339]}
Task 2 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=30616340-45924509]}
Task 0 --> RETURN_CODE = 206 ==> OK :-) !
Task 0 --> Start Byte = 0 / End Byte = 15308169 --> Total bytes = 15308170
Task 3 --> RETURN_CODE = 200 ==> NOK :-( !
Task 2 --> RETURN_CODE = 200 ==> NOK :-( !
Task 1 --> RETURN_CODE = 200 ==> NOK :-( !
```

Trick is between 2 runs code is same, remote host is same ... only target file is not same (second is half smaller than first and both are .zip files).
As requesting for some defined range I'm expecting for each task 206 return code what's acknowledging partial data will be received. But relying on second trace I'm getting for 3 latest task 200 code what's means server response is ok but will send full file :-( ....

What king of black magic may lead to such ????. Googling a bit I found some http server may introduce some range request coalesce process ... is such may happen here ?

> When multiple ranges are requested, a server MAY coalesce any of the
>          ranges that overlap, or that are separated by a gap that is smaller
>          than the overhead of sending multiple parts, regardless of the order
>          in which the corresponding byte-range-spec appeared in the received
>          Range header field.  Since the typical overhead between parts of a
>          multipart/byteranges payload is around 80 bytes, depending on the
>          selected representation's media type and the chosen boundary
>          parameter length, it can be less efficient to transfer many small
>          disjoint parts than it is to transfer the entire selected
>          representation.

Just for info here is my piece of java code :

```
HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
try {
    urlConn = task.openConnection(task.getSourceFileUrl());
    urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConn.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + currentByte + "-" + endByte + "");

    System.out.println(String.format("Task %s --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  %s", id, urlConn.getRequestProperties().toString()));

    if (urlConn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Task %s --> RETURN_CODE = %s ==> NOK :-( !", id, urlConn.getResponseCode()));
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println(String.format("Task %s --> RETURN_CODE = %s ==> OK :-) !", id, urlConn.getResponseCode()));
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("Task %s --> Start Byte = %s / End Byte = %s --> Total bytes = %s", id, currentByte, endByte, urlConn.getContentLengthLong()));
```

Thks for help !!!!!

Comment: i guess there's nothing wrong with your code. The server decided not to split the smaller file. By the way, if you request the smaller one in two chunks, would the server respond 206 for them?

Comment: I've done trial splitting smaller file by 2 instead 4 leading roughly to same 30Mb amount as the working trace : bad luck same unexpected behavior ...

'Task 0 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=0-30616339]}
Task 1 --> REQUEST PROPERTIES =  {Range=[bytes=30616340-61232679]}
Task 0 --> RETURN_CODE = 206 ==> OK :-) !
Task 0 --> Start Byte = 0 / End Byte = 30616339 --> Total bytes = 30616340
Task 1 --> RETURN_CODE = 200 ==> NOK :-( !'


What's boring / worrying me is sounds to me such coalesce process if such is root cause is quite unpredictable :-( ...

Comment: unless you can tweak the server configuration, you're short of options here unfortunately

Comment: Downloading a file with parallel connections from the same host really doesn't make sense because TCP/IP will scale the best if you have exactly one connection to the target server. The only exception is if the target server tries to serve files with fair bandwidth quota and you want to cheat the system. I'd say that raise the limits on the server or respect the server owner and do not cheat the system.

Comment: If you see Section 4 of RFC 7233 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233#section-4 you'll find that the server may choose to ignore the Range header or answer some other range than you requested. You have to check for the HTTP status code (206 vs 200) and the actually returned Content-Range. If you need bytes not provided with the response `Content-Range`, you'll need to do another request.

Comment: About the case that failed: are you sure that you didn't have any additional connections to the server while running the test? For example, the server may allow up to 6 parallel connections and if the previous connections still have any connections to the server, the server may behave differently. Another reason could be load balancing on the other end where some backends do not actually support partial content at all.